# Handle threads with callbacks

Tags: java, android

Is it possible that in Android , after a successful request , to modify UI changes using just callbacks without specifying the runOnUIThread or something else related to threads ?

For example :
MView :

```
  public interface MView {
   void doChangesOnUI(String value); 
}
```

MainActivity :

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MView {
   private EditText etText;
   private CallbackClass callback;

   @Override  
   onCreate() {... callback = new CallbackClassImplementation(this);}

     @Override
     public void doChangesOnUI(String value){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              etText.setText(value); 
            }
          });
         }

   public void OnClick(..){
      callback.doRequest();  
      }

}
```

And here I do have my CallbackClass classes :

```
public interface CallbackClass{ void doRequest();}

public class CallbackClassImplementation implements CallbackClass{

  private MView view;

  public CallbackClassImplementation(MView view){ this.view = view;}
  @Override
   doRequest(){
   doApiRequest.getData(String code,String message,String result){
    if (view != null) {
       view.doChangesOnUI(result);
         } 
    } 
   }
```

Regarding this code, is there any chance that I would be able to modify the UI without using runOnUiThread method ? Or if there is some nice trick to set the result to a callback. (I have tried with another callback, but the thread remains in the background). I totally want to avoid runOnUiThread or some other tricks like new Thread()..{...}

Comment: Callback is something which *calls back to original code with computation results*. The thing which you refer to as callback is not actually a callback - it is an *executor*. The callback in your code is represented by `MView` interface.

Comment: @lexraid i think, runOnUiThread is something android gift to you. i swear without this method you got write hell amount of code get the result to ui from background thread. Asyntasks, Handlers, Handler threads lot of options are there. You can try some but definitely come back to runOnUiThread. The other options are made for while you laying down thea architecture.

Comment: Alright @Sush , M. Prokhorov thank you both for information . I will look ahead on using runOnUiThread if there's any chance :D, just tried to do some self curiosity operation to see how threads could be handled even cleaner regarding java/android native behavior.

Comment: @lexraid, no, "if any chance" is a bad moto for using a tool. Best to understand both what it is, when it's used, and when it's not a good idea to use. Answering that wouldn't be good for this site though.